# Is there a Kotlin equivalent to Swift deinit?

Tags: android, kotlin

Swift provides a deinit function for every object and I am wondering if Kotlin has an equivalent function

Here is how it works in Swift (Apple Doc):

> A deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is deallocated. You write deinitializers with the deinit keyword, similar to how intializers are written with the init keyword. Deinitializers are only available on class types.
>
> Typically you don’t need to perform manual clean-up when your instances are deallocated. However, when you are working with your own resources, you might need to perform some additional clean-up yourself. For example, if you create a custom class to open a file and write some data to it, you might need to close the file before the class instance is deallocated.

Comment: You can override the `finalize` method. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())